# Codename one rounded URLImage not displaying

Tags: java, image, codenameone, mask

I am attempting to pull an image from a url using URLImage.createToStorage. However I want that picture to appear rounded so I add a Mask to the image. However when I run the label only shows the placeholder image, not the url image. When I comment out the code that adds the rounded mask to the image the image displays. Is there something wrong with my rounded image code. I used Display.getInstance().callSerially().

```
//Where I display the image. 
public void setUpProfile(Form f) {
    Label imageLabel = findMyImage(f);
    Image img = getImageFromRes("myprofile.png");
    Image scaled = img.scaledWidth(f.getWidth() / 2);
    EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.createFromImage(scaled, false);

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageLabel.setIcon(getRoundedImage(URLImage.createToStorage(enc, 
            "profileImage8", me.getPicture(), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL)));
            f.revalidate();
        }
    });

    findProfNameLabel(f).setText(me.getName());
    findProfAgeLabel(f).setText(me.getAge() + " Years old");
    findProfPrefLabel(f).setText("Interested in " + me.getPref());
}

public Image getRoundedImage(Image img) {

    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();

    Image maskImage = Image.createImage(w, h);
    Graphics g = maskImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(0xffffff);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, w, h, 0, 360);

    Object mask = maskImage.createMask();
    Image ret = img.applyMask(mask);
    return ret;
}
```

The setUpProfile() method is called in the beforeShow of the Form.

EDIT: I edited in the working setUpProfile() method which uses URLImage.createMaskAdapter. and achieves a rounded image.

```
public void setUpProfile(Form f) {
    Label imageLabel = findMyImage(f);
    Image mask = getImageFromRes("rounded-mask.png");
    Image placeholder = getImageFromRes("myprofile.png").scaled(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight());
    EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.createFromImage(placeholder.applyMask(mask.createMask()),   
false);
    System.out.println("SetUpProfile picture " + me.getPicture());

    imageLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(enc, "profileImage8",
    me.getPicture(), URLImage.createMaskAdapter(mask)));

    findProfNameLabel(f).setText(me.getName());
    findProfAgeLabel(f).setText(me.getAge() + " Years old");
    findProfPrefLabel(f).setText("Interested in " + me.getPref());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a custom `ImageAdapter` that generates a `round-mask` automatically for you while downloading the image.

```
public static final URLImage.ImageAdapter RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK = new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {
    @Override
    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        Image tmp = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight());
        if (tmp.getWidth() > placeholderImage.getWidth()) {
            int diff = tmp.getWidth() - placeholderImage.getWidth();
            int x = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(x, 0, placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight(), true);
        } else if (tmp.getHeight() > placeholderImage.getHeight()) {
            int diff = tmp.getHeight() - placeholderImage.getHeight();
            int y = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(0, y, Math.min(placeholderImage.getWidth(), tmp.getWidth()),
                    Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), tmp.getHeight()), true);
        }
        Image roundMask = Image.createImage(tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
        Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
        gr.setColor(0xffffff);
        gr.fillArc(0, 0, tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0, 360);
        Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
        tmp = tmp.applyMask(mask);
        return EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncAdapter() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then apply it this way:

```
public void setUpProfile(Form f) {
    Label imageLabel = findMyImage(f);
    Image img = getImageFromRes("myprofile.png");
    Image scaled = img.scaledWidth(f.getWidth() / 2);
    EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.createFromImage(scaled, false);

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(enc, 
            "profileImage8", me.getPicture(), RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK));
            f.revalidate();
        }
    });

    findProfNameLabel(f).setText(me.getName());
    findProfAgeLabel(f).setText(me.getAge() + " Years old");
    findProfPrefLabel(f).setText("Interested in " + me.getPref());
}
```

Comment: You can use `URLImage.createMaskAdapter()` which is even faster. The reason the original code doesn't work is that masking effectively replaces the image. So he creates a `URLImage` and before it has a chance to fetch the data he replaces it with the new masked image...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I edited in my new code which uses the URLImage.createMaskAdapter. The image is appearing now however it is not rounded. It's still a square.

Comment: Delete the contents of the .cn1 directory on your home directory and try again

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I deleted the contents and ran but the image is still not rounded.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog It's working I changed the image id. The square image was obviously cached.

Comment: Great! BTW I suggest accepting the answer from @diamond with the checkbox next to his answer as it will give both of you points that help with site-wide authority.